# Python script running both FastCGI and traditional CGI?

Tags: python, cgi, fastcgi

I have written a [Python script](http://azabani.com/cgit.cgi/pychan/tree/index.py?id=3b41017863e0b315fcbe73e6204c3d444f8351f4) that currently is designed to handle traditional CGI requests. Of course, this won't scale well as the overheads for each request are great, which is why I'm looking into implementing FastCGI support.

How can I modify my script to work with both CGI and FastCGI? Is there something the script can read from the environment that will identify if it is being spawned as either a traditional CGI request process or a FastCGI process? I don't really want to sacrifice traditional CGI support to implement FastCGI support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program to [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/) and use the [flup adapters](http://trac.saddi.com/flup).

Comment: Or.  Better yet.  Use mod_wsgi.